# What is $\| f \|$ where $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \langle x,e_n\rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

> Question:
>
> 1) Let $\{ e_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an ortonormal basis of a Hilbert space $H$.If $$x\mapsto f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \langle x,e_n\rangle$$ for all $x \in H$ , then determine $\| f \| \text{?}$
>
> 2) Every orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$ must be closed in $H$. (T\F)

work:
1) I find $f(e_n)=1/3^n,$ after that I cant manage. Please help.

2) I think 2 is false, as orthonormal set are dense in $H.$  Please help

Comment: Isn't $f(e_n)=\frac{1}{3^n}$?

Comment: *Wubba lubba dub dub!*

Answer (score 1):

user284331 has already given a hint for problem 2.

For 1, note that we can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get $$|f(x)| = \left|\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n}\langle x,e_n \rangle\right| \le \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{2n}}\right)^{1/2} \cdot \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left|\langle x,e_n \rangle\right|^2\right)^{1/2} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\|x\|$$ for all $x \in H$.

Equality holds if there exists a constant $C$ such that $\langle x,e_n \rangle = \dfrac{C}{3^n}$ for all $n$, i.e. $x = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \ \dfrac{C}{3^n} \cdot  e_n$.

From this, we get that $\|f\| = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: But why my argument that $|\left<x,e_{n}\right>|\leq\|x\|\|e_{n}\|=\|x\|$... is no good?

Comment: So essentially the so called $C$ can be taken as $1$.

Comment: Sure you could use Cauchy-Schwarz as you proposed, then you would get $|f(x)|\leq\Vert x\Vert\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{3^n}=\Vert x\Vert/2$ and thus $\Vert f\Vert\leq 1/2$. So you'd get an upper bound for $f$ but not the exact operator norm of it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Look up @JimmyK4542 for the bound.

Now put $x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}e_{n}$, this is defined since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}\|e_{n}\|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}=\dfrac{1}{2}<\infty$ and this attains the bound.

2) If this question were asking that if the **span** of the orthonormal set is closed, then look up any Hilbert space with Hamel basis of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

If the question were merely asking that if the orthonormal set is closed, then yes, as indicated by @Kavi Rama Murthy.

Comment: Isn't $f(e_1) = 1/3$ not $1/2$?

Comment: I think it goes through now.

Comment: If $x = \displaystyle\sum_{n  = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n}e_n$, then $\langle x,e_n\rangle = \dfrac{1}{3^n}$, and so, $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n  = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n}\langle x,e_n\rangle = \displaystyle\sum_{n  = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^n} \cdot \dfrac{1}{3^n} = \displaystyle\sum_{n  = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{2n}} = \dfrac{1}{8}$ not $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Also, $\|x\| \neq 1$.

Comment: Ah... you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You are right for the second question . you can in fact consider **any finite orthonormal basis** in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space

or you consider any separable Hamel basis and extract an orthonormal basis aftermath by the of **Gram-schimdt process**.

Whereas the first question is more technical. In fact it springs from Bessel-Parseval identity we have  $$\color{blue}{x=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\langle x,e_n \rangle e_n~~~~~and ~~~~~ \|x\|^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_n \rangle|^2} $$

Employing  Cauchy-Schwarzt inequalities it follows that,

$$\color{black}{|f(x)| = \left|\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}\langle x,e_n \rangle\right| \le \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{2n}}\right)^{1/2}  \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_n \rangle|^2\right)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\|x\|}$$

Now let $a= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\sqrt2}{3^{n}}e_n $   from Bessel-Parseval identity aigain we have  $$\|a\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{8}{3^{2n}} = 1 ~~~and~~~\langle a,e_n\rangle= \frac{2\sqrt2}{3^n}$$

Then, $$\color{red}{ f(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\sqrt2}{3^{2n}} =\frac{2\sqrt{2}}8= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}$$
Hence by definition of the operator norm, we have

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \ge \|f\|=\sup\{\|f(x)\|: \|x\|^2=1\}\ge f(a)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

therefore,

$$\color{red}{\|f\|= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}}$$

Comment: Hello, $f(e_{n})=\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}$? I made similar mistake just now.

Comment: @user284331 I just realize that the first bound was not sharp. thanks . I took me a while to see it

Comment: Actually we don't really need that strong $\|f\|=\sup\{\|f(x)\|: \|x\|=1\}$? I mean, it is equivalent to $\sup\{\|f(x)\|: \|x\|\leq 1\}$, then by taking $a=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}e_{n}$, one shows $\|a\|=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: For $a=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3^{n}}e_{n}$, I think it is $\|a\|^{2}=\dfrac{1}{4}$?

Comment: But then $f(a)=\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{8}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$?

Comment: Ah... now I know the trick, actually your choice goes through, and as @JimmyK4542 noted, if such $C$ exists, then it goes through, then $a=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}e_{n}$ works, although this is no $\|a\|=1$, but this does not matter.

Comment: For $a=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{n}}e_{n}$, $\|a\|^{2}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{3^{2n}}=\dfrac{1}{8}$, so $\|a\|=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is a continuous linear functional given by the Riesz Representation as
$$
   f(x) = \langle x,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}e_n\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle.
$$
The norm of such a functional is
$$
     \|f\|=\|y\|=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{2n}}\right)^{1/2}
    = \frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{9^n}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-1/9}\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}.
$$